# How to set date that is coming from API in react-js?

Tags: reactjs, api, date, datetime, jsx

```
 else if (ColType === "Date") {
   return (
<>
  <td
  className="text-left"
 //`enter code here`data-order={item.data[j]}
   >
  <input
   type="Date"
   name="chartSort"
   value={moment(item.data[j]).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
   className="input_height wd-130"
   readOnly={c.Editable ? false : true}
   onChange={(e) => {this.handleChangeGeneralLedgerList(e,item.data, i,j);}}
   />
 </td>
  </>
      );
      }
```

In this ColType is a type of column in which data of row will show up.
the date is coming from rows that I have mapped.

item.data[j] date is present in data
1 : "20/02/2003"

Data of date that is coming from API.

I don't know how to show incoming data from API of date.

Comment: did you try changing the format to YYYY-MM-DD? 

In the docs the default format is YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty. Please check here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Still, I'm facing this issue, sir. I don't know how to show incoming dates from API and how to send updated dates back to API? The main thing is that I don't know about the format. How to set it?